Rust on canned goods from the environment
I have had some canned food stored under the sink and recently discovered some water had pooled around the base of the cans and caused rust along the bottom ring/outside.
I understand when rust appears on cans by itself it can indicate compromised internal structure of the can. However as the rust came from the outset of the can and doesn't seem too advanced, would these cans still be potentially safe to use?

Yes, cans can have some rust on the outside and still be safe, as long as the rust hasn't eaten through the can you're fine. If the can rots through the food will usually leak out, however some food in cans isn't liquid like refried beans or canned meat, so it's not always an indicator.
A better way to check is to pour the food out of the can into a separate bowl, keeping it separate from other food, then rinse the can out and fill it with water. If the can holds water then the food should be fine, if it leaks throw the food away.

Don't forget about cross-contamination!

I'm not sure what you mean by that @Arctiic, if you mean don't let potentially contaminated food come into contact with other food that's why I said put it into a bowl. I've edited to clarify that.

It was a reminder to be mindful of it while transferring the raw material.
